# SpreadJS: show headers even for empty sheets

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, spreadjs, grapecity

Library name: [GrapeCity's SpreadJS][1]

Need to show header even for empty sheets.
Right now, for an empty sheet, I only have this picture, no header.

Anybody have idea how to do it?

**EDIT: Table header missing**[image: Table header missing]

Answer (score 0):

You are able to customize your spreadsheets column header when initializing SpreadJS by setting the value of the column header like so:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var spread =
    new GC.Spread.Sheets.Workbook(document.getElementById("ss"),{sheetCount:3});
    var sheet = spread.getActiveSheet();
    // Set the desired string in column headers
    sheet.setValue(0, 1, "Column Header", GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
    sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 120.0,GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.colHeader);
});
```

Here is a link to SpreadJS docs for an additional reference: https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v14/online/sccustheader.html

Comment: Hello , I've updated question. No need to customize header, just need to show it , when sheet contain no data.

Comment: Hello Jalle, Thank you for updating this! To accomplish this you need to set the row count to zero like so: setRowCount(0)

Comment: No matter what I try, there is still Table header missing (see screenshoot)